# App crashes on iOS5 simulator and on profiler

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, crash, xcode-instruments

My app crashes on the iOS 5 iPad simulator after about 5 min of smooth running. This is the only crash reference I get from Xcode, when I try to do a profile run using zombies/memory leak, the app for some reason won't even load (splash-screen shows and then the app crashes), I have no clue what is causing this behavior, any ideas?

```
error: memory read failed for 0x0
```

[image]

More info: I use ARC, the app works well on iOS6 & iOS7

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem, have you solve it ?

Comment: Same issue happening after opening xcode9 beta and going back to xcode 8

Answer (score 2):

Try adding an *All Exceptions* breakpoint to your project.

1. Open the *Breakpoint Navigator* (left side of Xcode)
2. Add *Exception Breakpoint*.

Run your code again and see if a specific point causes a crash.  Without seeing code, it's difficult to provide a specific answer.

[image: Breakpoint]

Comment: I already had an All Exceptions breakpoint. It did not help in this situation.

Comment: This does not help since crash is caused due to memory leaks or out of memory condition. Profiling is one way to debug.